# How to release a mobile app successfully?

Tags: iphone, android, mobile, release, distribution

This includes everything that contributes to the success of the app and is non-programming.

Some points to consider:

- How do you make people notice your app when there are hundreds released every week? How to get an article published in a mobile app blog about your app? Should you buy ads? What about a press release?
- How to shoot a promotional video? What material is good? Should you go for animation or real life footage?
- How to make a project website for the app? Should it be simple in design? What about feedback forum? Should you use standard forum like, uservoice.com?
- To which marketplace should you release the app? Should you stick to one or as many as you can?
- Should you wait with releasing until you have all these handled or should you do it immediately? Is there a good time to release your app?

Answer (score 2):

[The River of News maker writes](http://blog.riverofnewsapp.com/2011/03/update-how-much-money-can-you-make-on.html):

"What I didn't expect was how much River of News sales were driven by 
**continually updating with new features. Even if the beneficiary of those features were customers who already paid**, it creates a fall-out effect of discussion and more sales."

Angry Birds was not doing well either until they started doing something similar.